# Load Vector Layer from table using processing in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to turn a CSV of data into a shapefile using processing.

```py
mStasIn = "C:\GIS_Abschluss\AirData\MeasurementStations.csv"
mStasOut = "C:\GIS_Abschluss\AirData\MeasurementStations.shp"


mStas = QgsVectorLayer(mStasPath, "mStas", "ogr")

processing.run('qgis:createpointslayerfromtable',
            {'INPUT' : mStasIn,
            'XFIELD': 'xcoord',
            'YFIELD': 'ycoord',
            'ZFIELD': 0,
            'MFIELD': 0,
            'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:32633', 
            'OUTPUT': mStasOut})

iface.addVectorLayer(mStasOut, 'mStas', "ogr")
```

This creates a shapefile, but there are no points on my canvas.

Comment: Your script looks correct, but it's impossible to verify without also seeing the CSV contents

Comment: I've also tested your script, with some testdata and it works. So check your CSV like Nyall pointed out in his comment. By the way, it is better to avoid the backslash in path definitions in python, because some characters in combination with backslash have a special function like "\n" is a new line. so better use normal slash for that.